# SQL Server : How to replace whitespaces(&nbsp, ASCII) in a string with numbers?

Tags: sql, replace, numbers, int

This works   `select replace('string with space',' ','')` and returns stringwithspace.

This does not work `select replace('8 190',' ','')`, it returns 8 190

This is the same `select replace('8     190',' ','')` returns 8 190.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: missing a space in your first ''  try `select replace('8 190',' ','')` instead

Comment: Because your need to add a space in the second  argument between the ' '.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string_pattern needs to contain the ASCII code 160 for the space `&nbsp`

```
SELECT REPLACE('8 190', char(160),'')
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the typo, I wanted to correct that, as it returned the same result, I later found out that, the space character (' ') was in fact &nbsp which has the ASCII code 160.

Comment: It is worked for me. I was directly passed "&nbsp;" in second parameter but when I have passed "char(160)" at second parameter then I got the result and save my time to solved my query related this. Thanks Buddy.